Why did changing the orders of my imports in nestjs impact my dependancy injection?
I got this errors
    at QueuesProducerService.emit (libs\shared\src\queues\queues-producer\queues-producer.service.ts:30:24)
    at ProducerService.sendStatusUpdate (apps\server\src\chemistryrx\producer\producer.service.ts:17:17)
    at ChemistryrxService.updateOrder (apps\server\src\chemistryrx\chemistryrx.service.ts:39:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at ChemistryrxWebhooksController.updateStatus apps\server\src\chemistryrx\webhook\chemistryrx-webhooks.controller.ts:35:14)
    at node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17

With this module
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forFeature(healthUpdateTrackerConfig),
    QueuesProducerModule.register({
      clientId: 'hh-backoffice',
      brokers: process.env.QUEUE_BROKERS.split(','),
    }),
    QueuesConsumerModule,
  ],
  providers: [HealthUpdateTrackerService, ProducerService, StorageService],
  controllers: [ConsumerController, HealthUpdateTrackerController],
})
export class HealthUpdateTrackerModule {}


When reversing ConfigModule and QueuesProducerModule it work perfectly.
@Module({
  imports: [
    QueuesConsumerModule,
    ConfigModule.forFeature(healthUpdateTrackerConfig),
    QueuesProducerModule.register({
      clientId: 'hh-backoffice',
      brokers: process.env.QUEUE_BROKERS.split(','),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [HealthUpdateTrackerService, ProducerService, StorageService],
  controllers: [ConsumerController, HealthUpdateTrackerController],
})
export class HealthUpdateTrackerModule {}


I try to understand why moving the ConfigModule at index 1 make me code work.
Here the rest of the code you may needs.
@Injectable()
export class ProducerService {
  private context = `HealthUpdateTracker${ProducerService.name}`;
  private readonly logger = new Logger(this.context);

  constructor(private readonly client: QueuesProducerService) {}

  sendHealthUpdateTrackerUpdated(healthUpdateTracker: HealthUpdateTracker): void {
    const dto: HealthUpdateTrackerDto = HealthUpdateTrackerDto.fromModel(healthUpdateTracker);
    this.logger.log(`Add ${queuesConstants.BACKOFFICE.HEALTH_UPDATE_TRACKER.UPDATED} for: ${dto.id}`);
    this.client.emit(queuesConstants.BACKOFFICE.HEALTH_UPDATE_TRACKER.UPDATED, dto);
  }
}

@Module({})
export class QueuesProducerModule {
  static register(config: { clientId: string; brokers: string[] }): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: QueuesProducerModule,
      providers: [QueuesProducerService],
      exports: [QueuesProducerService],
      imports: [
        ClientsModule.register([
          {
            name: 'kafka',
            transport: Transport.KAFKA,
            options: {
              client: {
                clientId: config.clientId,
                brokers: config.brokers,
              },
            },
          },
        ]),
      ],
    };
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class QueuesProducerService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('kafka') private readonly client: ClientKafka,
    @Inject(CONTEXT) private request: RequestContext | IncomingMessage | undefined,
  ) {}

  private isIncomingMessage(obj: RequestContext | IncomingMessage | undefined): obj is IncomingMessage {
    return (
      !!obj &&
      'headers' in obj &&
      HEADER_TRACKER_ID_KEY in obj.headers &&
      obj.headers[HEADER_TRACKER_ID_KEY] !== undefined
    );
  }

  emit<R, T>(queueName: QueueName, obj: T): Observable<R> {
    if (this.isIncomingMessage(this.request)) {
      return this.client.emit(queueName, {
        requestId: this.request.headers[HEADER_TRACKER_ID_KEY] as string,
        body: obj,
      });
    }
    return this.client.emit(queueName, { requestId: this.request?.data?.requestId, body: obj });
  }
}


Also if I am not using QueueProducerModule and using ClientsModule instead directly into my HealthUpdateTrackerModule and changing my constructor of ProducerService for injecting
@Inject('kafka') private readonly client: ClientKafka, it's working with ConfigModule at index 0.
I will also add somewhere in another module we got the ConfigModule at index 0 and the QueuesProducer work as expected.
